# Create new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that will contain worksheets with the text “benefits” in the sheet name.  For example; MEDICALBenefits or DENTALBenefits.  There will always be at least one, but there could be several.

I am trying to write a macro that will find the worksheet(s) with the text “benefits” in the sheet name AND at least one instance of the word TRUE in row 40.

When these two criteria are met then I need to create a new worksheet using the same worksheet name but replacing the text “Benefits” with the text “Final”, In other words; If the worksheet MEDICALBenefits has TRUE in one or more cells in row 40 then a new sheet called MEDICALFinal would be created.

Likewise, if the worksheet DENTALBenefits has TRUE in one or more cells in row 40 then a new sheet called DENTALFinal would be created.

I then need it to loop through all the sheets looking for “Benefits” in the name and TRUE in row 40 and create a new sheet.

This is the code I have so far, but need help with naming the new sheets.

Jordan

```
 'Look for worksheet names *benefits* with checkbox(s) = true
Sub CreateFinalWorksheet()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim iVal As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("40:40"), "TRUE")
        If (LCase$(sh.Name) Like "*benefits*") And (iVal > 0) Then Call AddWorksheet
    Next sh
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


'Called from CreateFinalWorksheet.
'Add worksheet with same sheet name replacing *benefits* with *final*
Sub AddWorksheet()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = "MedicalFinal"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** after OPs clarification he wants to find all "*benefits" sheets

in

```
iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("40:40"), "TRUE")
```

you're missing current `sh` worksheet reference, so you want to write as follows:

```
iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("40:40"), "TRUE")
```

For what above and for your main issue, I'd go like follows:

```
Sub CreateFinalWorksheet()
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If (LCase$(sh.Name) Like "*benefits") Then
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Rows(40), "TRUE") = 0 Then AddWorksheet sh.Name
        End If
    Next sh
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub AddWorksheet(shtName As String)
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.count)).Name = Replace(LCase$(shtName), "benefits", "Final")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried both suggestions and both creates a new sheet MEDICALFinal, but doesn't loop to the next sheet DENTALBenefits to create the next new sheet DENTALFinal. I thought after calling the sub it would return to the first macro and loop through the rest of the sheets.  I'm very new to VBA and not sure how to make needed modifications.

Comment: @JordanCA57, see edited answer. If it solves your question please mark it as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thank you

Comment: I only  had to change the equal to to great than.  That I understand.  The rest I will go though and figure it out.  This is really helpful for learning.

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter to your `AddWorksheet` routine, let it be the "benefits"worksheet

```
If (LCase$(sh.Name) Like "*benefits*") And (iVal > 0) Then AddWorksheet sh

Sub AddWorksheet(benef as worksheet)
    ....
    ws.name = Replace(benef.name, "benefits", "Final", , vbTextCompare)
```

Eventually, you can also do other things inside this sub, such as copying some data from the parameter worksheet `benef`.

Comment: It creates a new sheet MEDICALFinal, but doesn't loop to the next sheet DENTALBenefits to create the next new sheet DENTALFinal.  I thought after calling the sub it would return to the first macro and loop through the rest of the sheets.

Comment: @JordanCA57 it does, what I showed is just a way to modify your routine and to call it. Also think of fixing some other issues in your code unrelated to the question, i.e. qualify your ranges..